# Custom login button VS. fbml button

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For a few days i was trying to use a custom button to invoke login

```
$(".join").live("click", login);

    function login(){
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response) {
                console.log('Login success.');
                FB.api("/me", handleMe);
            }
            else {console.log('Login cancelled.')}
        });
    }


    function handleMe(response) {

        $.ajax({
            async: 'false',
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'www. address.com',
            data:
                "uid=" + response.id + 
                "&name=" + response.name,

            success: function(){
                console.log('Ajax successful.');
                console.log("<?php echo $this->session->userdata('fb_uid'); ?>");
                window.location = "www. address.com";
                },
            error: function(){console.log('Ajax failed.');}
        });
    }

    $(".join,.log,.biggie-btn").live("click", login);
```

However it was always buggy, the login window would not close (oddly, most of the times) and after I closed it, I would not get the user FB.API details, and I had to refresh the page to get them.

As soon as I switched to  the bugs were gone (having exactly the same functionality), however I can't control now the style of the login button.
Is there a solution, to have a fully functional custom login button?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Facebook javascript SDK and easily build your own login button.  Just have the button class FB.login and pass it a callback function and optionally any extended permissions you need.  Upon success, this will set a cookie that has an access_token that you can use from server code if needed.  Otherwise, you can just call javascript sdk functions.

**Here is an example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="doLogin();return false;">Custom Login Button</a>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({ appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml : true });

  function doLogin() {  
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.session && response.perms) {
        FB.api('/me',
          function(response) {
            alert('User: ' + response.name);
            alert('Full details: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
          }
        );
      }
    } , {perms:'user_about_me'}); 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey for those looking to do this in the new framework here is a useful Facebook developers blog https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/07/21/updated-javascript-sdk-and-oauth-2-0-roadmap/